# How to check file exists is case insensitive

Tags: perl, file-handling

I want to check if a file exist in Perl. This can be done using `(-e $filename)`. But this is case sensitive. How can I check for case insensitive. I have to use only core package to achieve this.

Comment: See [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=113442) page.

Answer (score -1):

Stolen from [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Perl/Q_24328305.html).

```
(grep {/$file/i} <$dir/*>) or die "$file not exist in $dir\n";
```

Comment: You would want `/^\Q$file\E\z/`